# Convert View Rect coordinates to bitmap area

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-camera2

I have camera screen with rectangle(simple view) inside, to make photo the user need to place object inside the rectangle, after taking picture the app need to cut image and show only the area inside rectangle.

- From `camera2` api i receives the image and converting him to `bitmap`.
- I have the Rectangle coordinates on screen.

The problem is that the `bitmap` `width`/`height` for example 5472/7296, and the `Rect` coordinates related to device screen left-114 top-764 width-852 height-609, how i can convert it to area on bitmap to cut the bitmap in `Rect's` area.

I am cutting the bitmap using

```
Bitmap createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

I have tried to calculate with percentage but it not ideal(about 5% inaccuracy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution was to scale the bitmap to screens size.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapUtil.scaleBitmap(bitmap, screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

Then crop by the `Rect` cordinates

```
Bitmap cropBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, rect.left, rect.top, rect.width(), rect.height());
```

Comment: I tried this it was kind of helpful but it compromises with the quality and aspect ratio? I too am struggling with the same problem. I need to crop the image inside the portion of the rect but not being able to do.