# Crop the captured image on the basis of Rect Cordinates in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am trying to crop out the portion inside the RoundRect. I have an overlay on top of PreviewView. The horizontal margin is 2% of the screen width and top is 15% of the screen height.

When I take the picture, I want to crop it with the same proportion as the RoundRect displayed. As the resolution of the captured image is different than that of the screen, I am not being able to get the exact portion inside the rounded rectangle. Is there anyway I can use the margin value used for the RoundRect to get the margin value for the captured Image?

I did try scaling it down to the screen size [as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60148392/5130133) and crop it but even that doesn't help as quality and aspect ratio gets compromised.

I am using bitmap to crop the captured image.

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBp, left, top, right, bottom);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The outputs are aligned with the crop rect. The crop rect of different use cases should be mapped to the same area on the camera sensor. If you are using PreviewView, a simple way to calculate the transform from Preview to ImageCapture is using [CoordinateTransform](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/transform/CoordinateTransform):

```
 // Build the transform from PreviewView to Capture
OutputTransform source = previewView.getOutputTransform();
OutputTransform source = FileTransformFactory().getOutputTransform(capturedFile);
CoordinateTransform coordinateTransform = new CoordinateTransform(source, target);
 
 
coordinateTransform.mapRect(roundRect);

// Then use roundRect to crop the capture file.
```

Comment: can you clarify the comment "Then use roundRect to crop the capture file." ? How we should crop the imageProxy with the rect?

Comment: You need to first convert the ImageProxy to a Bitmap, then crop the Bitmap..